# why function run indefinitely in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to test by button click functionality using `jasmine` .But when I run my test runner it run `indefinitely` why .I write test case like that

```
xit('should called service method on button click', inject([SignupserviceService], (signupserviceService: SignupserviceService) => {
  spyOn(signupserviceService, 'signUpHandler');
  let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn')
  button.click();
  expect(signupserviceService.signUpHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

when you remove `x` front of `it` browser reload `indefinitely`.I am not sure why it happening ?

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-kdb8ka?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

any update

Comment: Because it's a submit button, which by default submits a form, ie reloads the page.

Comment: how to `prevent` default

Comment: can you please give better solution